# How to use the information of a file readed with sap.ui.unified.FileUploader?

Tags: file, view, sapui5

I'm using this namespace to take a File that has information (some Excel tables)and I just want to know how take that information to display it in my view? I know it is something related with a JSON file to save the information or something like that, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achived with JavaScript, but it will require third-party libraries.

In a nutshell, you have to listen to the `change` event:

```xml
<u:FileUploader change="onFileChange" />
```

In your controller, you can then read the Excel file:

```js
onFileChange: function(oEvent) {
    var aFiles = oEvent.getParameter("files");
    if (aFiles && aFiles.length) {
        this.processFile(aFiles[0]);
    }
}
```

The `processFile` method depends on what third-party library you will use. In the end, you want to convert the Excel into a JSON and store it into a local [JSONModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel).

For example, if you use [JS-XLSX](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), it could look like so:

```js
processFile: function(f) {
    var oModel = this.getModel("myLocalModel");
    var oReader = new FileReader();
    oReader.onload = function(e) {
        var oWorkbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type: 'array'});
        var oSheet = oWorkbook.Sheets[oWorkbook.SheetNames[0]];
        var oData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(oSheet);
        oModel.setData(oData);
    };
    oReader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```